# Connecting to service port of a docker container from gitlab host results in Connection Refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am facing this issue while trying to connect to a service started on a docker container from the host.

I have a gitlab-ci.yml file which contains configuration similar to the one below:

```
e2e-test:
  before_script:
    - git clone repo_x
    - cd repo_x
    - docker-compose up -d
```

Now, repo_x contains a docker-compose file with a service that maps serviceport 3000 with the host port 3000 as below

```
service_x:
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

Now, if I run wget localhost:3000 in the script part of the gitlab-ci stage, I see an Connection Refused error. I am also unable to connect to the service at port 3000 from any program which I start in the host.